# Is this issue resolved in Apache Flink 1.15.1?

Tags: apache-flink

I am looking into the issue [FLINK-28060](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-28060). And I think that it is resolved and it will be included as the resolved one in Apache Flink 1.15.1. When I look at the release note of the Apache Flink at [release note](https://flink.apache.org/news/2022/07/06/release-1.15.1.html), the issue still remains unresolved for 1.15.1. But the jira-issue is closed and the resolution level is fixed.
At the version 1.16 the issue will be included but I am wondering that why this issue is not included in the 1.15.1 or 1.15.2 but in the 1.16 ? Does this issue have special reason to be updated later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that issue is not resolved in Flink 1.15.1. The necessary fix to Kafka wasn't made until well after 1.15.1 was released.

FLINK-28060 was caused a bug that was introduced into Kafka in the version of Kafka bundled with Flink 1.15.0. The necessary fix to the Kafka client was recently made available by the Kafka community, and the Flink community decided there was enough time to thoroughly test this new Kafka release before 1.16.0 will be completed, so it will be included there.

If you are using Flink 1.15.x and are troubled by this bug, you can work around it by excluding from your JAR the buggy version of the kafka client bundled with Flink, and build against the newer version instead. (This should be possible unless you are running a pure SQL job, rather than submitting a JAR file.)